# integration by parts partial derivatives

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

I have a question about integration by part and application in case with partial derivative.
Is the following true ?
$$ \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} f(x,y)g(x,y)dx=f(x,y)G(x,y)-\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} G(x,y)dx $$ where
$$G(x,y)=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}g(x,y)dx$$
I am not sure that I can define $G$ that way.
Thank you

Comment: Is ok if you take $u=f(x,y)$ and $dv=g(x,y)$, then you have. $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y)g(x,y)dx=\left[f(x,y)G(x,y)\right|_{-\infty}^{+ \infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{dx}G(x,y)dx$